# how to connect bonita bpm with mysql database?

Tags: mysql, business-process-management, bonita

I want to connect Bonita bpm with a mysql database.based on a simple process created by Bonita studio, I tested the mysql driver and I configured the connector with hostname: port/database and I created a simple output query but no result.

Comment: Do you see an error in the logs? Studio -> Help -> Bonita BPM Engine log. If not, make sure that the connector has been correctly executed by checking the status of your task in the Administrator view.

Comment: the error is   : "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.bonitasoft.engine.bpm.connector.ConnectorExecutionException: USERNAME=install |

Comment: org.bonitasoft.engine.core.connector.exception.SConnectorException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.ConnectorException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."

Comment: You probably should update the question with that error message instead of putting it in the comments.